# Calling send_flow API of SurveyMonkey is giving an unexpected error

Tags: rest, http-post, surveymonkey

Even though my request is giving all the required parameters in JSON body , why is it giving the following error?

API : https://developer.surveymonkey.com/docs/methods/send_flow/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have `id` under the collector field. That's not an allowed attribute. `send_flow` creates a new collector and email message and attaches them to an existing survey so you can't select a collector that already exists. Just remove that from your payload and you shouldn't get that error anymore.

```
{
    "survey_id": "111237200",
    "collector": {
        "send": true,
        "recipients": [{
            ...
        }]
    },
    "email_message": {
        "subject": "Ice and Fire event",
        "reply_email": "sunil@ljhjhjk.com"
    }
}
```